# Como montar JSON com uma lista de lojas separadas por categorias?

Tags: javascript, json

Não tenho muita intimidade com JSON e estou precisando criar uma estrutura em que conste uma lista de lojas separadas por categorias, onde cada item de loja possua algumas informações (nome, piso, telefone etc.) Até pensei em fazer um JSON para cada categoria, mas gostaria que ficasse tudo num objeto só para depois poder iterar.

Tentei algo como abaixo mas não está dando muito certo:

```
var ljs = {
   "categ": "Loja de Departamentos",
   "lojas": [
      {
        nome: "LOJA A",
        piso: "1",
        tel: "",
        desc: "descrição da loja.",
        imagem: "logo_a.jpg"
      },
      {
        nome: "LOJA B",
        piso: "1",
        tel: "",
        desc: "descrição da loja.",
        imagem: "logo_b.jpg"
      }
      ]
};
```

Além de `"categ": "Loja de Departamentos"` terão ainda várias outras categorias, como Docerias, Restaurantes etc. Creio que a chave `"lojas"` seja até desnecessária.

Como posso montar um JSON desse tipo, onde conste as categorias e a lista de lojas para cada uma e depois eu possa puxar os dados com um `for`?

Comment: Existem lojas que estejam em mais do que uma categoria ? Se for o caso é mais facil inverter e fazer um array de lojas em que cada loja tem um array de categorias.

Comment: Não, apenas em 1 categoria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você também pode usar o nome da categoria como key:

```js
var ljs = {
  "Categ 1": {
    "lojas": [
      {
        nome: "LOJA A",
        piso: "1",
        tel: "",
        desc: "descrição da loja.",
        imagem: "logo_a.jpg"
      },
      {
        nome: "LOJA B",
        piso: "1",
        tel: "",
        desc: "descrição da loja.",
        imagem: "logo_b.jpg"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Categ 2": {
    "lojas": [
      {
        nome: "LOJA C",
        piso: "3",
        tel: "",
        desc: "descrição da loja.",
        imagem: "logo_c.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
};

for(cat in ljs) {
  let lj = ljs[cat]
  console.log("Nome da categoria:", cat)
  console.log("Lojas:", lj.lojas)
}
```

OBS.: Confesso que não acho legal colocar palavras acentuadas como chave.

Answer (score 4):

Um jeito simples seria assim:

```js
var ljs = [
  {
    "categ": "Categ1",
    "lojas": [
      {
        nome: "LOJA A",
        piso: "1",
        tel: "",
        desc: "descrição da loja.",
        imagem: "logo_a.jpg"
      },
      {
        nome: "LOJA B",
        piso: "1",
        tel: "",
        desc: "descrição da loja.",
        imagem: "logo_b.jpg"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categ": "Categ2",
    "lojas": [
      {
        nome: "LOJA C",
        piso: "3",
        tel: "",
        desc: "descrição da loja.",
        imagem: "logo_c.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
];

for(i in ljs) {
  let lj = ljs[i]
  
  console.log(lj.categ, lj.lojas)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basta você empacotar os dados das categorias em um array raiz. Você pode dar um nome para o campo que guardará a raíz (no exemplo eu usei `dados`), ou como foi sugerido na outra resposta, transformar `ljs` em um array ele mesmo.

Assim:

```
var ljs = {
    "dados": [
        {
           "categ": "Loja de Departamentos",
           "lojas": [
              {
                nome: "LOJA A",
                piso: "1",
                tel: "",
                desc: "descrição da loja.",
                imagem: "logo_a.jpg"
              },
              {
                nome: "LOJA B",
                piso: "1",
                tel: "",
                desc: "descrição da loja.",
                imagem: "logo_b.jpg"
              }
            ]
        },
        {
           "categ": "XYZ",
           "lojas": [
              {
                nome: "LOJA X",
                piso: "3",
                tel: "",
                desc: "descrição da loja.",
                imagem: "logo_x.jpg"
              },
              {
                nome: "LOJA Y",
                piso: "2",
                tel: "",
                desc: "descrição da loja.",
                imagem: "logo_y.jpg"
              }
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
};
```